# Retrieving the Qwidget from a ui file

Tags: c++, qt

I have a group project and I was wondering if I could just "convert" their ui files (stock.ui) into `Qwidgets` and use the function `Qwidget::insertwidget()` to add it to my `StackedWidgets`

Comment: ui files are just containers, they have inside they widgets....

Comment: If you used the wizard of QtCreator you might have created a class when you created the ui file. Very often, a container QWidget is added by the IDE and instanciates your ui file as a private member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the QUiLoader class: 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html#details

I also recommend reading [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) to learn more on Ui files management.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm.Here is the code
    `QUiLoader loader;
    QFile file("F:/SmarterMarket/untitled - Copy/arduinocontrol.ui");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QWidget *myWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
    ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(7,myWidget);
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(7);
    file.close();`

Comment: you should also add the uitools in the .pro file like such  `QT+= uitools` and include `#include <QUiLoader> #include <QFile>` in your cpp file